# resize.cpp:4052: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, android, flutter, opencv, flask

I am taking the picture from my app and uploading it on flask and on flask I am running the below python code to take the recently uploaded image from flask and perform the detection and extracting the number plate of vehicle from the image.
The actual error I ran into is the image is uploading on flask safe and fine but is showing invalid for the detection in the form of above error.

```
from fileinput import filename
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import werkzeug


app = Flask(__name__)  #creating flask server


@app.route('/upload', methods=["POST"])   #defining the route of pages
def upload():
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        imagefile = request.files['image']
        imagefile2=str(imagefile)
        # print('12132')
        filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
        
        imagefile.save("./uploadedimages/"+filename)
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
        
        img = cv2.imread(imagefile,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        # print (imagefile2)
        img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(600,400) )
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 13, 15, 15) 
        edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200) 
        contours = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
        contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
        screenCnt = None
        
        for c in contours:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.018 * peri, True)
            
            if len(approx) == 4:
                screenCnt = approx
                break
        
        if screenCnt is None:
            detected = 0
            print ("No contour detected")
        else:
            detected = 1
            
        if detected == 1:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        
        mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)
        new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask,[screenCnt],0,255,-1,)
        new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
        
        (x, y) = np.where(mask == 255)
        (topx, topy) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
        (bottomx, bottomy) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
        Cropped = gray[topx:bottomx+1, topy:bottomy+1]
        
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Cropped, config='--psm 11')
        print("programming_fever's License Plate Recognition\n")
        print("Detected license plate Number is:",text)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(500,300))
        Cropped = cv2.resize(Cropped,(400,200))
        cv2.imshow('car',img)
        cv2.imshow('Cropped',Cropped)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        return jsonify({
            "message":"Uploaded"
        })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000 )
```

I have tried converting the image into string but didn't worked out. I am using flutter for app.
And below the is the app screen code where the response of the flask is being recieved.

```
uploadImage() async {
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST", Uri.parse("https://6a6d-59-103-181-239.ngrok.io/upload"));

    final headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};

    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile('image',
        selectedImage.readAsBytes().asStream(), selectedImage.lengthSync(),
        filename: selectedImage.path.split("/").last));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    final response = await request.send();
    http.Response res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    final resJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    message = resJson['message'];
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`cv2` bindings for OpenCV have cryptic ways of telling you that you inadvertently passed `None`. Here

```
img = cv2.imread(imagefile,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

is likely returning None, possibly because you meant to pass

```
"./uploadedimages/"+filename
```

instead of `imagefile`.

Comment: I have made changes as you said now its giving error: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

Comment: You've advanced to a new and different problem, which now requires a posting a new Question